# unable to upload png files using python to azure devops wiki

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a png file as attachment in azure wiki using python and getting the following issue:

*azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: The wiki attachment creation failed with message : The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.*

This is the snippet

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v5_1.wiki.models import GitVersionDescriptor

personal_access_token = '<pat>'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/<org-name>'

credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
wiki_client = connection.clients.get_wiki_client()

version_descriptor = GitVersionDescriptor(version="main", version_type="branch")
with open("./sample-image.png","rb") as png_file:
    wiki_client.create_attachment(  upload_stream=png_file,
                                    version_descriptor=version_descriptor,
                                    project="<project-name>", 
                                    wiki_identifier="<wiki-name>", 
                                    name="sample-image.png" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Python. But according to the error message, it seems that there is a problem with the input format of your image.

According to this REST API [Attachments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP), Media Types should be application/octet-stream". So the image needs to be converted to Base64.

Here are my PowerShell scripts for reference:

```
$Image_Path = "<your image path>"
$Base64_Code = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$Image_Path"));
$token = "<your PAT>"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/wiki/wikis/<wikiId>/attachments?name=<Wiki attachment name>&api-version=6.0"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $head -Body $Base64_Code -ContentType application/octet-stream
```

The result of the above script:
[image]